# Failed to create symbolic link?

Tags: linux, raspbian-stretch

I'm trying to symlink file `/etc/systemd/network/00-default.link` to `/boot/00-default.link`. This allows me to force a change to my MAC address from the `boot` directory, which is the only directory accessible from my Mac computer when I plug in the SD card.

However, when I use the command:

`sudo ln -s /etc/systemd/network/00-default.link /boot/00-default.link`

I receive the error:

`ln: failed to create symbolic link '/boot/00-default.link': Operation not permitted`

Any idea what might be causing this?

*Note: I've created `/etc/systemd/network/00-default.link` already but I have not yet created `/boot/00-default.link`*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your earlier questions, I know why you want to do this from boot, and symlinking `/boot/00-default.link` to `/etc/systemd/network/00-default.link` doesn't help, because `/etc/systemd/network/00-default.link` seems to be processed before `/boot` is mounted - therefore `/etc/systemd/network/00-default.link` is a broken link at the time it is being processed

I don't know if this is fact, but I know that linking that way also doesn't help, so I am assuming it to be fact :p

Here's a solution I came up with :p

Create a service in `/etc/systemd/system` - lets call it `macoverride.service`

```
[Unit]
Description=Copy user mac_override.link
ConditionPathExists=/boot/mac_override.link
After=local-fs.target

[Service]
Type=oneshot
RemainAfterExit=yes
ExecStart=/bin/mv /boot/mac_override.link /etc/systemd/network/00-default.link
ExecStartPost=/sbin/reboot

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

note about `After=local-fs.target` - I played around with this a bit, there may be an *earlier* target you can use, or use `Before=` - but this one works

Now, enable it

```
sudo systemctl enable /etc/systemd/system/macoverride.service
```

What this service does is

1. if `/boot/mac_override.link` exists - **move** it to `/etc/systemd/network/00-default.link`
2. reboot

Now, since step 1 **move**s the file, it won't exist after the reboot - so there's no chance of a reboot loop :p

> Here's a more generic solution, by generic, I mean you'll be able to change what the file on the boot partition can do

Create a file for example, /etc/systemd/system/ssmatt.service

```
[Unit]
Description=Super special Matt code (change this to suit :p)
ConditionPathExists=/boot/matt.sh
After=basic.target

[Service]
Type=oneshot
RemainAfterExit=yes
ExecStart=/bin/sh /boot/matt.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

and

```
systemctl enable ssmatt.service
systemctl start ssmatt.service
```

Now, create a `matt.sh` file in the boot partition

```
#!/bin/sh
ifconfig eth0 down
ifconfig eth0 hw ether 10:00:00:00:00:11
ifconfig eth0 up
```

again `After=basic.target` is just the earliest target I found where this code was reliable for changing MAC

Using this method, the one downside is that `matt.sh` must exist in boot partition for the MAC to be changed, however the up side is that you can use `matt.sh` to do more than just changing the MAC

Comment: The OP might want to consider accepting this answer as it addresses the "implicit" issue of the question far better than mine ;) Your approach reminds me of what Raspbian is doing with the `wpa_supplicant.conf` file that is magically transferred from `/boot` to the correct spot somewhere in `/etc`.

Comment: @Ghanima - your answer actually answers the question though, so more useful for "future readers" - I've helped the OP in two other questions, so I kinda know the overall picture of what he's trying to achieve - as such, while this answer does provide a possible solution (there are others) this doesn't really answer the question, and so, not really helpful to anyone but Matt :p

Comment: This is beautiful. Can't thank you enough again @JaromandaX. Spot on as always. Cheers

Comment: Which do you think you'll use? the mac override or the "super special" :p

Comment: @Ghanima agreed, although your answer more directly addressed my question, this answer provides a solution to address the underlying issue. To any future readers take a look at Ghanima's answer to see why this issue is occurring.

Comment: @JaromandaX I'm leaning towards the mac override solution for simplicities sake but even just having the knowledge to execute a shell script from `/boot` using service files provides me with options I didn't previously have. I'm learning a ton from your answers.

Comment: @JaromandaX Ok weird follow up issue: so the mac_override method worked once and then randomly stopped working for me. When I create `/boot/mac_override.link` and use it to overwrite `/etc/systemd/network/00-default.link` it works (the file is moved successfully and pi reboots) but then doesn't change the MAC address. I thought this seemed weird so I tried forcing a change again with `ifconfig eth0 down; ifconfig eth0 hw ether 21:21:21:21:00:11; ifconfig eth0 up; ifconfig eth0` and that too has stopped working. It now gives the error `ether: Host name lookup failure`

Comment: Maybe this should be moved to chat now? Or I should start a new question?

Comment: The full output from `ifconfig eth0 down; ifconfig eth0 hw ether 21:21:21:21:00:11; ifconfig eth0 up; ifconfig eth0` can be seen [here](https://ideone.com/leUCob)

Comment: Actually, I've created a follow up question [here](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/90035/cannot-find-hw-ether-to-force-mac-address-change)

Answer (score 3):

`/boot` is a FAT filesystem that unfortunately does not support symbolic links.

So this cannot work

```
sudo ln -s /etc/systemd/network/00-default.link /boot/00-default.link
```

Turning it around and placing the file itself (source) on `/boot` and the link (target) on `/etc` however should do

```
sudo ln -s /boot/00-default.link /etc/systemd/network/00-default.link
```

This would however lack unixoid access permissions for the file - if that is an issue.

Comment: Interesting. I've noticed that if I move the file into `/boot/` then symlink that file into somewhere else it works fine though, how is it able to work in one direction and not the other though?

Comment: Follow up question - since `/boot/` requires a hard copy of the file and `/etc/systemd/network/` also requires a hard copy to change the MAC address, would it be possible to use an intermediary third symlinked file as a bridge between the two hard files (meaning I could edit hard file `/boot/00-default.link`, which would edit the symlink `/home/Pi/Desktop/bridge.link` which in turn would edit hard copy of `/etc/systemd/00-default.link`)? Hopefully that made sense

Comment: w.r.t. the first comment, so you have a link from a unixoid FS *to* the vfat partition? That's just fine.

Comment: correct, I have a hard file `/boot/my_script.py` with symlink `/home/Pi/Desktop/my_symlinked_script.py`

Comment: Thanks for adding that edit @Ghaninma, that clarified a lot. I believe in this case the lack of unixoid access permissions is causing an issue for whatever reason. Can you think of any way to get around that while still linking the file to `/boot/`